# How do I update Activity with intents passed via Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have created a custom notification, but when i pause the activity with the home button and a notification arrives, i press the notification and it creates a new activity and doesnt resume the previews activity and when i press the back button it goes to the previews one which is the same window. I have tried `singleTop, singleTask, singleIntent`, it works but it doesnt update the activity when a message enters, it is like the previews activity was in pause. how can i fix it?

if there is no solution i though  in resuming the activity or destroy the paused activity or maybe restart the activity, is there a way to do this?

```
public void CustomNotification(String strtext) {
        // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.customnotification);

        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle);
        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
        // Send data to NotificationView Class
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
        intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
        intent.putExtra("String T", "");
        //intent.putExtra("Integer C", 0);

        // Open NotificationView.java Activity
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
                        // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                        // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        // Set RemoteViews into Notification
                .setContent(remoteViews);

        // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.mipmap.ic_action_chat);

        // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle));
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, strtext);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
```

LOGS:

```
04-29 01:29:10.453  29001-29001/com.example.example E/STATE﹕NEW ACTIVITY
04-29 01:29:15.376  29501-29501/com.example.example D/Activity﹕ Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
04-29 01:30:06.981  29501-29501/com.example.example E/STATE﹕ RESUMING
```

WHEN I PRESS THE NOTIFICATION:

```
04-29 01:33:09.654  33449-33530/com.example.example E/STATE﹕NEW ACTIVITY
```

I will appreciate any answer, Thanks!

EDITED

ANSWER:

the answer was to add:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

because when i was in the same window and i pressed the home button, the activity was in paused, then if some notification arrived it brought me to that window but didnt updated the messages so I needed to create a new intent and erase the previous one which was in pause. so that code did the Job.

Comment: Have you defined onResume() method in your activity?

Comment: @Keshav1234 i did , why? does it causes problem? or do i have to  override it?

Comment: If you want to perform some thing when your activity resumes, you definitely need to override onResume() method and add all your resume operations in that method.

Comment: @Keshav1234 but when i press the notification it is not resuming , it is creating a new activity thats why.... and the previews activity is still on resume

Comment: If it is creating new activity then it seems that your activity is not getting paused, add log messages in onCreate and onResume and see which method is getting executed.

Comment: @Keshav1234, it is pausing just the first activity and resuming the first activity for first time, the second time i press the notification it creates a new one

Comment: @Keshav1234 is there a way to detect if the activity is paused? if so then i could check that and go to that activity

Comment: you should add log message in onPause and check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your service code to use notification :

```
 private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1222;
   NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     private void Notifi(String message){
        int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                //CLEAR PREVIOUS ACTIVITIES AND CREATE A NEW ONE
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagenameofyourapplication",
                        "packagenameofyourapplication.NotificationView"));
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_titel)).setContentText(message)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pintent).build();
                notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
                mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notif);

}
```

Comment: Why do you feel this is an answer, how will this solve the issue of the question according to you?

Comment: i think @Anshuman didnt read, i have already tried, single task

Comment: Actually after trying everything, this worked, as i said my notification was opening a new activity so Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP erased previews intents which were on paused, which was good for my app i didnt want to resume the previous activities but creating a new one so Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) made the job. thak you i didn't understand at first, this has been 4 days of research and many hours of debugging. I am a beginner and there are many others, so next time when posting an answer please explain it. THANKS it helped me a lot

Comment: @kobbycoder that is one way to solve this issue. But if you (or someone else) would like to reuse the previous instance while updating the few things only, my answer would come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

To update your activity, you should override `onNewIntent()`:

```
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //reload your data here
}
```

[Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) say:

> `void onNewIntent (Intent intent)`
>
> This is called for activities that set `launchMode` to "singleTop" in
>   their package, or if a client used the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag
>   when calling `startActivity(Intent)`. In either case, when the activity
>   is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new
>   instance of the activity being started, `onNewIntent()` will be called
>   on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch
>   it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so
>   you can count on `onResume()` being called after this method.
>
> Note that `getIntent()` still returns the original Intent. You can use
>   `setIntent(Intent)` to update it to this new Intent.

**Note:** as the docs say, you need to set `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your Activity tag (in AndroidManifest).

Comment: if i set single Top it will make my program works differently, wouldn't it take time to load it? i mean at least more milliseconds? and I have a function that creates a backup after the intent is destroyed(encrypted data) so i make it run on a thread. That's why i say my app would work differently.

Comment: @kobbycoder sorry for the delayed response. Differently - yes. You may like to read [Android: Understanding Activity launch mode](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode) to have a better understanding.